# Toggle Fullscreen (overrideredirect and geometry)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm using Tkinter with Python 3.2.3 on my Raspberry Pi, and I'm trying to make a checkbutton that toggles whether the window is in fullscreen or not. I'm running into two problems:

First, when I use `Root.overrideredirect(True)`, everything works perfectly, but when I use `Root.overrideredirect(False)`, nothing happens and the window does not regain it's borders.

Second, when I use `Root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(Root.winfo_screenwidth(), Root.winfo_screenheight()))`, the buttons (Which I built to auto-centre themselves) automatically realign to the centre of the screen, but the window itself does not change size.

Why is this and how do I make it work?

After trying a solution, this is the current situation:

```
Root = Tk()
Mark0 = False

def Loop(): #Always looping
    if Fullscreen.get() and not Mark0:
        Root.overrideredirect(True)
        Root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(Root.winfo_screenwidth(), Root.winfo_screenheight()))
        Root.withdraw()
        Root.deiconify()
        Mark0 = True
    elif not Fullscreen.get() and Mark0:
        Root.overrideredirect(False)
        Root.geometry("320x240")
        #Root.withdraw()
        #Root.deiconify()
        Mark0 = False
    Root.after(5, Loop)
```

Results in:

-Toggle On 1:
    -Window loses border

-Toggle Off 1:
    -Window is shoved into upper left hand corner of screen
    -Border remains missing

-Toggle On 2:
    -Window goes fullscreen properly

-Further toggling repeats from Toggle Off 1

```
Root = Tk()
Mark0 = False

def Loop(): #Always looping
    if Fullscreen.get() and not Mark0:
        Root.overrideredirect(True)
        Root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(Root.winfo_screenwidth(), Root.winfo_screenheight()))
        Root.withdraw()
        Root.deiconify()
        Mark0 = True
    elif not Fullscreen.get() and Mark0:
        Root.overrideredirect(False)
        Root.geometry("320x240")
        Root.withdraw()
        Root.deiconify()
        Mark0 = False
    Root.after(5, Loop)
```

Results in:

-Toggle On 1:
   -Window loses borders

-Toggle Off 1:
   -Window regains borders

-Toggle On 2:
   -Window disappears

Any explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered  that the solution is complicated, but the reason my code did not work is because tkinter's main loop only seems to be able to process one change to the window per loop (And it seems to loop about 200 times per second). Thus, doing

```
Root = Tk()
Root.geometry("1000x1000")
Root.overrideredirect(True)
```

will cause tkinter to only process the override redirect, and forget about the geometry. The solution is to use Root.after(int, func) to call overrideredirect and follow up functions (withdraw and deiconify) more than 5 milliseconds later.

Unfortunately, even with all that it is still unstable (Though usually works). My best guess is that if the CPU is overloaded with programs or interrupts or whatnot, it can cause the speed of tkinter's main loop to mess up, which results in one of the function calls being ignored. This likely isn't a problem on most computers, but is certainly an issue on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

You need to withdraw and then redisplay the window, so that the window manager can be notified that it needs to redraw (or remove) the borders. Use the `withdraw` and `deiconify` methods of the root window.

Comment: That sort of worked at first (Window would lose borders, then shove itself into upper left corner when I turned fullscreen off, then go fullscreen proper when I turned it on the second time), but when I added those methods to return it to a normal window on fullscreen off, it only loses borders when I turn fullscreen on first time, then returns to window properly on fullscreen off, then disappears on fullscreen on second time.